# Kubernetes: kubeadm init - CGROUPS_PIDS: missing

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, kubeadm, cgroups

I am trying to run `kubeadm init` but I get this error during preflight: `CGROUPS_PIDS: missing`

```
kubeadm init phase preflight

[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 3.13.0-37-generic
CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
CONFIG_INET: enabled
CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled
CONFIG_PROC_FS: enabled
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_OVERLAYFS_FS: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_AUFS_FS: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled
DOCKER_VERSION: 19.03.8
DOCKER_GRAPH_DRIVER: aufs
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
CGROUPS_PIDS: missing
CGROUPS_HUGETLB: enabled
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR SystemVerification]: missing required cgroups: pids
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

`kubeadm` version:

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:25:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Ubuntu version 20.04 running on Digital Ocean VM. I have previously had a kubernetes cluster on this same VM (also using kubeadm), but after a crashed cluster and Ubuntu upgrades this error now appears when trying to recreate the cluster from scratch (I ran `kubeadm reset` first).

After hours of Googling I still have no idea how to fix this or even what it means. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update**

Output of kernel config CGROUPS:

```
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep CGROUP
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
# CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_BLK_CGROUP is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP=m
CONFIG_NETPRIO_CGROUP=m
```

---

**Update: Solved**

It turned out that my cloud provider overruled the kernel to be an older one (3.x). After changing the setting, the Ubuntu GRUB-initiated kernel (5.x) is running, which has **CGROUPS_PIDS** enabled.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ? Output of `uname -r` and `lsb_release -a`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may report the fact that your kernel does not define the *pids* cgroup. The latter is provided by Linux kernel if the **CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS** is defined.

Look at your kernel configuration. Under Ubuntu, you can run something like:

```
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep CGROUP 
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_WRITEBACK=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_RDMA=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
# CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_SOCK_CGROUP_DATA=y
# CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP_IOLATENCY is not set
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP_IOCOST=y
# CONFIG_BFQ_CGROUP_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CGROUP=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP=m
CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_PRIO=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_CLASSID=y
```

Then, check if your kernel is built with **CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS**. In the above display, it is set.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I updated my question with the output, and it does not contain PIDS. I am using standard Ubuntu, and I have not messed around with the kernel, other than what APT does for me on upgrade and dist-upgrade. Any idea how to fix this or why the setting has disappeared?

Comment: Solved. I found out that my cloud provider (Digital Ocean) had a setting overruling the chosen kernel, so no matter which kernels and kernel settings I set up in Grub and the boot process, the hypervisor would overrule it. Thanks for your help!